# Uploading an image to server in android without changing in multipart form

Tags: java, android

In my app i am trying to upload an image on grails server, problem is that converting the image into base 64 format is not getting accepted at the back end, server developer says it should not be in multipart form. 
Here is my code:

```
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);           

     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
     byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
     String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT);

     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileupload",image_str));


     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "trial"));

     try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         Log.i(TAG, " http reponse is:" +response);
         convertResponseToString(response);
     }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:text="Browse gallery"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**uploadfile.java**

```
public class uploadfile extends Activity {
    TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        doFileUpload();
    }

    private void doFileUpload(){

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;
          DataInputStream inStream = null; 


          String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
          // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.

          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary =  "*****";


          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

          byte[] buffer;

          int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

          String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";



          try
          {


          Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");

          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );



           URL url = new URL(urlString);

           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           conn.setDoInput(true);

           // Allow Outputs
           conn.setDoOutput(true);

           // Don't use a cached copy.
           conn.setUseCaches(false);

           // Use a post method.
           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

           conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);


           dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
           dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
           dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

           Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");



           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           buffer = new byte[bufferSize];



           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

           while (bytesRead > 0)
           {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           }



           dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                           conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                    tv.append(inputLine);




           // close streams
           Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
           fileInputStream.close();
           dos.flush();
           dos.close();


          }
          catch (MalformedURLException ex)
          {
               Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
          }

          catch (IOException ioe)
          {
               Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
          }


          //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE


          try {
                inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                String str;

                while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                {
                     Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
                }
                /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

                }*/
                inStream.close();

          }
          catch (IOException ioex){
               Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
          }



        }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], "./".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

?>
```

Comment: do you have any example of server side code in java. I mean instead of php can we write in java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to use multipartEntitiy the example is like this :

```
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL_HERE);

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        if (Photo != null) {

            mpEntity.addPart("photo", new ByteArrayBody(Photo,
                    "YOURPHOTO.png"));
        }

        try {

            if (Photo != null) {
                myConnection.setEntity(mpEntity);
            }

            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            result.setResult(BaseID.REQUEST_DATA_MEMBER_CREATE_FAILED);
            result.setError_title("Exeption Title");
            result.setError_message("Exeption Messege");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I hope you can understand my answer if you have any question about my answer please feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: Do i need to add any jar file, because it shows entity unresolved on ( MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);) this line itself.

Comment: @user1472202 ah yes I forgot to mention you need to download httpmime-4.2.2.jar from here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.2/